# Bluetooth versus Wireless for VoIP

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, voip

I am about to change my phone to a VoIP phone, and I want to connect to the phone wirelessly.

I have been offered a Bluetooth solution and a Microsoft wireless solution at approximately the same price.

Which one is better, and why?

EDIT: I believe this is the actual wireless device I am talking about.
http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/digitalcommunication/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited answer)

If your computer already has bluetooth, I would go for the bluetooh one as it means no additional device needed. If you do not have Bluetooth, I would go with the Microsoft adapter as I find the hardware generally very good and that headset looks nice!

---

General advice for wireless V bluetooth headsets-

Typically, if I understand you, a Bluetooth VOIP phone would be a simple headset/microphone that connects to a computer and needs a driver / third party software to actually connect to a VOIP provider.

A Wireless VOIP device will simply be straight on to your network without requiring any other computer device. You put the VOIP settings straight into it.

Again, without knowing model numbers or more info, it is hard to tell - I am just talking about a typical Bluetooth headset and a wireless VOIP phone.

Comment: Thanks Wil. I guess I wasn't clear. The wireless solution is simply a headset/microphone similar to the Bluetooth device. 

I expect the wireless option to be a bit more complex to set up, but I believe that they are very similar in their usage. I hope this makes it clearer.
Don

Comment: On re-reading your answer, I believe you are saying that the wireless connection will completely bypass the computer and connect directly to the wireless network???

When I first read it I thought you were describing a "Skype Phone". Maybe this is a similar solution.

Comment: Ok, I completely understand now - I thought you were describing a skype phone type device... Personally, I do like quite a bit of Microsoft hardware and would go for it - however if your laptop/desktop already contains bluetooth, use that at it means no extra usb adapter needed... if you need to get a adapter anyway, I would go for the Microsoft one - it looks nice and will probably work well!

Comment: Hi Wil.

I have done quite a bit of research into the Microsoft device and find that most (85/90%) of people who tried it and bothered to write a comment were VERY negative. They cite installation, connection, useful range and especially sound quality, both received and sent as being problematic.

Based on this, at this time, I am leaning toward the Blue Tooth solution, but I have been informed that the BT solution has a very short range and that generally sound quality is a problem also. Do you have any advice or knowledge as to this?

Thanks for your responses.

Don

Comment: I have generally found MS hardware to be excellent. Bluetooth would probably give you a maximum (in good quality) of about 5 metres. Personally though, I would ask the reseller what the average distance is on the MS one, then buy it and if it doesn't live up to your expectations, take it back.

Comment: Also, remember that if you have a bad experience with something, you are a lot more likely to complain rather than say how good something is when you are happy!